# How do you formally prove $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(|na_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}) = \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

My definition of $\limsup$ is it is the supremum of the accumulation points of a sequence (i.e the supremum of the limits of all possible subsequences of a sequence). So if:
$$\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(|na_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}) = L \implies \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \in \mathbb{N},|na_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} < L $$

But I don't see why both have to be equal.

Comment: It's essentially because $n^{1/n}\to 1$.

Comment: your statement of limsup is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{1 \over n} = 1$, notice that given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $N_{\epsilon}$ such that for $n > N_{\epsilon}$ one has
$$1  < n^{1 \over n} < 1 + \epsilon$$
Use this to show that for $n > M_{\epsilon}$ one has
$$\sup_{k \geq n} |a_k|^{1 \over k} \leq  \sup_{k \geq n} |ka_k|^{1 \over k} \leq  ( 1 + \epsilon) \sup_{k \geq n} |a_k|^{1 \over k}$$
I think you can take it from there...